# Delete certain data from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot mapping species abundance (count) by year, with each species being a different color. There are some species with no data or insignificant data that I am trying to get rid of. So far I have this:

```
 ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Count,
                                 color = Species)) + geom_line()
```

The graph is exactly what I want, but I can't figure out how to remove a species' data from the graph so it looks a little cleaner.

This is what the data looks like:

```
  Year   Species      Count
1 1992 American Toad     2
2 1993 American Toad    12
3 1994 American Toad    13
4 1995 American Toad   120
5 1996 American Toad   144
6 1997 American Toad    82
```

Comment: Subset your `df` data.frame before passing it to `ggplot`. Drop the groups you don't want to plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment you can use `dplyr` to `filter` out rows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
    filter(Species != "unwanted species") %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Count, color = Species)) +
    geom_line()
```